# Android Lock OnTouchListener

Tags: android

I have a thread running showing some stuff, but there is also a onTouch event, what I want to do is to lock the OnTouch while the other Thread is running and when it is done then allow the OnTouch to work again..?

How can I achieve this?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a flag that indicates if a thread is running. Then you can do this in your onTouch method:

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
   if (!threadIsRunning) {
      //do you stuff here
   }
}
```

And in your thread you can set the flag in the run method:

```
public void run() {
   isThreadRunning = true;
}
```

As soon as your thread is finished, you set the flag back to false:

```
isThreadRunning = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

return `false` if a thread is running on onTouchListener and `True` if all thread job is done.